What is the source for the teaching, ‘Shame is intelligence, intelligence shame’?
I came across this teaching a while ago - it came from a reputable source. I am quite sure the source was pre-acharonim.
Does anyone know who said it and where?

It doesn't mean that shame IS intelligence, but that shame (modesty) is the measure of a child's intelligence - once they care for modesty they can be considered intelligent and have Halachic consequences.

I do not know the ultimate source, but here is the opening of Orkhos Tzaddiqim's discussion of the value of the Middah of Bushah, the capacity to experience shame or embarrassment:

הַבּוּשָׁה. אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים: הַשֵּׂכֶל הוּא הַבּוּשָׁה, וְהַבּוּשָׁה הוּא הַשֵּׂכֶל. כִּי עַל אָדָם וְחַוָּה נֶאֱמַר (בראשית ב כה): ״וַיִּהְיוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם עֲרוּמִּים הָאָדָם וְאִשְׁתּוֹ, וְלֹא יִתְבֹּשָׁשׁוּ״ – וְלֹא הָיוּ יוֹדְעִים הַצְּנִיעוּת וּלְהַבְחִין בֵּין טוֹב וּבֵין רָע. וּלְאַחַר שֶׁאָכְלוּ מֵעֵץ הַדַּעַת נֶאֱמַר (שם ג ז): ״וַתִּפָּקַחְנָה עֵינֵי שְׁנֵיהֶם״.


The Sages have said: "Intelligence is a sense of shame and a sense of shame is intelligence." For regarding Adam and Eve, it is said: "The two of them were naked and yet they felt no shame" (Gen. 2:25). And they did not understand what modesty is and they could not distinguish between good and evil. But, after they had eaten of the Tree of Knowledge, it is said: "Then the eyes of both of them were opened" (Gen. 3:7).

(The Orkhos Tzaddiqim, originally named Sefer haMiddos, was written in Germany in the 15th century CE. The author is unknown.)
I was not able to find where the sages said this, nor did the footnote providers in the editions of Orkhos Tzaddiqim that I own. I invite edits and comments from those who can trace this thought yet earlier.
The author continues using this idea in subsequent paragraphs. See Sefaria's copy of Orkhos Tzadiqim sec 3, "On Shame".
